# how to insert form data into a web service with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, ionic-framework, asmx

I am trying to map a Ionic mobile app with a deployed web service.

I want to insert form data so that it can be updated in the database via a .NET asmx web service. the ajax code is as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5096/AndroidWebService.asmx/InsrtTblEmp', type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: //what to do here?,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var jEl = $("#divMessage");            
            jEl.html(result.d).fadeIn(1000);
            setTimeout(function () { jEl.fadeOut(1000) }, 5000);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

here is the code for the asmx web service:

```
    [WebMethod]
    //public string InsrtTblEmp(int EmpId, string LeaveType, DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo, float? LeaveDays, string Remarks)
    public string InsrtTblEmp(TblEmpLeaveDat TblEmpDat)
    {
        string msg ="";
        try
        {
            var obj = new tblEmpLeave()
            {
                EmpId = TblEmpDat.EmpId,
                LeaveAvailType = TblEmpDat.LeaveAvailType,
                DateFrom = TblEmpDat.DateFrom,
                DateTo = TblEmpDat.DateTo,
                LeaveDays = TblEmpDat.LeaveDays,
                Remarks = TblEmpDat.Remarks
            };
            Db.tblEmpLeaves.Add(obj);
            Db.SaveChanges();

            msg = "Record insert successfully";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            msg = ex.Message;
        }

        return msg;
    }
}
```

Now from what i understand, the web service is only accepting an object datatype. first question: can i create objects in jquery?

will it be more efficient to use this web service as it is? or should i modify it so that it takes hard coded string values rather than the object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are passing in tblEmptDat, which is of type TblEmpLeaveDat, is there a reason why you are creating obj, instead of just using the passed in object?

Comment: the webservice code is incomplete, maybe it is being passed in another method.. let me check. and thanks for the help ! i do feel that i have made some progress, although i am still ending up in the error part of the ajax

Comment: You could try using the code I show below, but manually setting known values in to the properties. This will check the code passes the values in the ajax call ok.
You can also use Fiddler to inspect the calls. This will show you what is being passed in the ajax call: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: i think the problem now lies in figuring out how to pass the ajax string as an object to the web service

Comment: That is shown in my answer below, where I create var formData = {...}; Then pass formData in the ajax data property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the names of the fields in your form are the same as they are in your model, you can do this:

```
var frm = $(document.myform);
var formData = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:5096/AndroidWebService.asmx/InsrtTblEmp', 
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        var jEl = $("#divMessage");            
        jEl.html(result.d).fadeIn(1000);
        setTimeout(function () { jEl.fadeOut(1000) }, 5000);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert("An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

If the form names are different, you set the data in formData like this:

```
var formData= {
              EmpId: $('.input1').val(),
              LeaveAvailType: $('.input2').val(),
              DateFrom: $('.input3').val(),
              DateTo: $('.input4').val(),
              LeaveDays: $('.input5').val(),
              Remarks: $('.input6').val()
              };
```